# Multiple Postbaks on click event

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

Ok, here is a thing, i have five main divs in my code, mainClientList, mainTable1, mainTable2, mainTable3 and mainTable4. mainClientList contains a list of clients and for each client its information is displayed on click in the rest of the divs. Also i have a checkbox, when checked the information of each client is displayed one by one and for this i have used setInterval. In set interval i have trigered a click event which postbaks.

Now the problem is when i put update panels on these five divs, they work fine when user clicks on some client, but when the checkbox is checked multiple postbaks occurs. Why is this happening ??

Please help...

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chboxRefresh" Checked="false" OnClick="startStopTimer();" runat="server" />
    <div id="mainClientList">
        <input type="hidden" name="reference" id="chboxRefresh_hidden" runat="server" value="" />
        <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" style="display:none;" OnClick="Btn_Click" />                    
       <table class="gridtable">
            <tr>
                <td id="row1_1"><asp:CheckBox ID="chk_cl1" runat="server" /></td>
                <td id="row1_2">
                    <div><asp:LinkButton ID="cl1" runat="server" Text="a" OnClick="cl_Click" /></div>
                    <div><br /><asp:Label id="lastUpdatecl1" runat="server" CssClass="lastupdatedclients"></asp:Label></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="row2_1"><asp:CheckBox ID="chk_cl2" runat="server"/></td>
                <td id="row2_2">
                    <div><asp:LinkButton ID="cl2" runat="server" Text="b" onclick="cl_Click" OnClientClick="$('#loader').show();"/></div>
                    <div><br/><asp:Label id="lastUpdatecl2" runat="server" CssClass="lastupdatedclients"></asp:Label></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="row3_1"><asp:CheckBox ID="chk_cl3" runat="server"/></td>
                <td id="row3_2">
                    <div><asp:LinkButton ID="cl3" runat="server" Text="c" onclick="cl_Click" OnClientClick="$('#loader').show();"/></div>
                    <div><br/><asp:Label id="lastUpdatecl3" runat="server" CssClass="lastupdatedclients"></asp:Label></div>
                </td>
            </tr>                     
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="mainTable1">
        some table
    </div>

    <div id="mainTable2">
        some table
    </div>

    <div id="mainTable3">
        some table
    </div>

    <div id="mainTable4">
        some table
    </div>
</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function startStopTimer() 
    {         
        setInterval(pageReload, 10000);           
    }
    function pageReload() 
    {
        clearInterval(intervalIDSelect);
        document.getElementById('<%=btn.ClientID %>').click();
    }

</script>
```

Whem checkboxRefresh is checked startStopTimer is trigered which postbaks.

Comment: Please most some code, I'm finding it hard to visualize what you're describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please set checboxes autopostback properties as true
and

code behind

```
   public void checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
          //write here your codes
         }

    }
```

I hope I can help you

Comment: It doesn't help, the problem occurs only when startStopTimer() executes

Comment: I had same problem.And this codes solved my problem.But sorry